# Adjoint Transformation

Tags: linear-algebra, inner-products, linear-transformations, adjoint-operators

Let $V$ be a finitely-generated inner product space and let $\alpha,\beta_1,\beta_2 \in \text{End}(V )$
satisfy $\alpha^* \alpha \beta_1 =\alpha^* \alpha \beta_2$ . Show that $\alpha \beta_1 = \alpha \beta_2$.

$\alpha^*$ is defined as the adjoint transformation of $\alpha$.

Any help/suggestions are greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Suppose $x \in V$. Then our hypothesis implies that $\alpha^* \alpha (\beta_1 - \beta_2) x = 0$. Hence
\begin{align*}
0 &= \langle \alpha^* \alpha (\beta_1 - \beta_2) x, \ (\beta_1 - \beta_2) x \rangle \\
&= \langle \alpha (\beta_1 - \beta_2) x, \ \alpha(\beta_1 - \beta_2) x \rangle. 
\end{align*}
Thus $\alpha (\beta_1 - \beta_2) x = 0$. Because $x$ was an arbitrary element of $V$, this implies that $\alpha \beta_1 = \alpha \beta_2$, as desired.